# Valgrind error dereferencing an address returned by std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, dereference

Why does valgrind returns an error for this piece of code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int *ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(i);
        if (i == 100)
        {
            ptr = &vec[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << ptr << "\n";  // Print address of -> Ok
    std::cout << *ptr << "\n"; // Print content of -> Ok but with a valgrind error
}
```

Compiled with: `g++ -Wall -Wpedantic -O0 -o demo demo.cpp`

The valgrind error is:

```
==3982== Invalid read of size 4
==3982==    at 0x1093A7: main (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==  Address 0x4dae1e0 is 400 bytes inside a block of size 512 free'd
==3982==    at 0x483E1CF: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3982==    by 0x109EB4: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x109B5B: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::deallocate(std::allocator<int>&, int*, unsigned long) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x10970F: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate(int*, unsigned long) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x109A3B: void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_realloc_insert<int const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x10964F: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x109354: main (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==  Block was alloc'd at
==3982==    at 0x483CE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3982==    by 0x10A0FF: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x109F73: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x109DAD: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x1098BC: void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_realloc_insert<int const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x10964F: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==    by 0x109354: main (in /home/david/demo)
==3982==
```

It makes me doubt whether dereferencing an address returned by a vector has undefined behavior, is this legal code?

Comment: Due to the reallocation problem, where both pointers and iterators to elements can too easily become invalidated, it's better to save *indexes* instead.

Comment: Another possible solution is to set the size of the vector before, and just use indexes. Or in your case it could be solved with [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead of the explicit loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP is not asking for a workaround though, they're quite clearly asking whether the shown code is legal or not.

Comment: @cigien Well I'm not writing an answer, only comments.

Comment: @cigien true, but any suggestion is welcomed. The question comes because libraries that "reallocates memory" do not make this point clear at all, for example [g_array](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html) (from glib) uses a similar concept (using `realloc`) and I think it would be very opportune to clarify it since it can introduce bugs. I see that it is the same case with `std::vector` but it may be that in this case it is well documented, is there any reference in the standard?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you had gotten this code from some library. Yes, Some programmer dude's suggestions are certainly a better way of going about this. Note that in general, reading relatively old library code is not a great way to learn how to write code today. There are various reasons for this, the primary one being that tools we have today were simply not available before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Valgrind says it's an "invalid read". During the `push_back` operation the `std::vector` will reallocate memory if required and copy all the data to anew location.

If so, it is possible that your `ptr` is pointing to memory which is no longer allocated to the vector `vec`.

So yes, it might be UB the way you are using it.

It's better to `reserve` the memory first if you already know the number of elements you are going to insert, and then simply insert the elements at the correct location.

Comment: Actually, I think it only *might* be UB. An implementation could have allocated enough memory so that no reallocation is done after the address of an element is taken.

Comment: @cigien: Yes you are right. I will update

Comment: an other way is to not get the address of an element for a future use but its index in the vector

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer to clarify the bit about the UB. I've made a few minor edits to clean up the answer a bit, hope that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the last part of the question about dereferencing pointers to vector indexes.

Please correct me if I am wrong but its my understanding that the elements in a vector are just pointers to the actual data. The array of vector elements must be in contiguous memory so they can be indexed but the data can be anywhere.

Expanding a vector is quick because you only have to move the indexes to a new bigger block of contiguous memory, not the actual data. The first time you expand a vector with .push_back the array of indexes WILL move in memory so any pointers you had to them will become invalid, after the first time its implementation specific.

Comment: _elements in a vector are just pointers to the actual data_. Can you elaborate on that? As far as I understand a vector is a pointer to a contiguous area of memory, something like a growable array ... _the data can be anywhere_... if you mean they are an array of pointers where each element is in fragmented memory, I think you are wrong.

Comment: Well I really mean what I say. If you dereference the name of a vector it will give you the current address of the first element in an array of pointers to your data.

Comment: I think one of the main features of a vector is that it doesn't matter how big your data type is because when you expand a vector only pointers to the data ever get moved so its quick. C++ style strings are very similar to vectors but storing a pointer to a single character would be silly in this case so the data IS actually stored in the index.

Comment: I disagree  (a vector doesn't store pointers) but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't mean C/C++ style pointers. The indexes of a vector are handles or "vectors" to the data elements but they still point at the data, they are not the actual data.